# Integrate FHIRBase with HAPI FHIR database

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I have an `HAPI FHIR` database where I've stored my FHIR resources (as `Patient`, `ServiceRequest` and so on).

Now I want to querying my database but, for example, if I want to write a query involved an extension I can't do it.

So I've googled about using of FHIR Base to query a FHIR database.

I don't know if I can integrate my HAPI FHIR database (I've used `Postgresql` DBMS) with FHIR base

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your data is structured in HAPI FHIR database.
If your schemas match the FHIRBase schemas then is just a config issue.

You should do an ETL (extract-transform-load). Use a messaging queue (e.g. Kafka) and process your messages as SQL queries to populate the resourceType and resourceType_history tables (or call the procedures e.g. create_resource but this is because they are not bulk)